# Saving an array to userdefaults in Yosemite isn't working? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsarray, plist, nsuserdefaults

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:string forKey:keyString];
  NSMutableArray *returnArray = [self returnAllEntriesInformationforkey:keyString];
if (![returnArray containsObject:string]){
    [self.newDataArray addObject:dict];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.newDataArray copy] forKey:@"Datanew"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The above code works perfectly fine in Mavericks and Lower, however in Yosemite and El Capitan it isn't adding the data to the "Datanew" array key in the defaults plist.

I've tried using the below instead of doing a copy of the array also with no luck:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.newDataArray forKey:@"Datanew"];
```

If I add a test into the code, the key Cheese is created and "I like Cheese" is added to the plist, but the array data is not added to the Datanew key - i'll repeat it works in Mavericks and below - any ideas why?

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:string forKey:keyString];
  NSMutableArray *returnArray = [self returnAllEntriesInformationforkey:keyString];
if (![returnArray containsObject:string]){
    [self.newDataArray addObject:dict];
}

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.newDataArray copy] forKey:@"Datanew"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"I Like Cheese" forKey:@"Cheese"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

The data in the array is used for autofilling, the data in the array is read originally from the Datanew key in the plist and data is added later on as the user fills in data. If I output the content of the Array into the console here is what it displays - the issue isn't with data, it's not saving even with fresh entries.

```
08/10/2015 20:21:20.449 MyApp[12981]: array data (
    {
    mail = "myemail@gmail.com";
},
    {
    mail = "test@test.co.uk";
},
    {
    mail = "test@gmail.com";
},
    {
    username = myusername;
},
    {
    first = "Latest News";
},
    {
    "post_title" = Example;
},
    {
    first = "Information is here";
},
    {
    "ctl00$pagecontent$ctlxlayouttime" = "0:30";
},
    {
    first = Adam;
},
    {
    q = "google search";
},
    {
    "post_title" = Facts;
},
    {
    mail = testtest;
}
)
```

Comment: What are the contents of the array?

Comment: I've updated my post to explain the array

Comment: Why don't you just save your array as an XML file in the sandbox folder assigned to your application?  It'll take just one line of code.

Comment: Because this plist is backed up to a server - changing it now would smash up a lot of things - I don't understand why it's not working now but worked perfectly fine in Mavericks.